# Rename all files that match with a regex

Tags: python, linux

I have the files in following format:

```
abc-h-25-Data.db
abc-h-25-Filter.db
abc-h-25-Index.db
abc-h-25-Metadata.db
abc-h-25-Statistics.db
abc-h-25-Summary.db
```

Need to rename by replacing the h by j as follows:

```
abc-j-25-Data.db
abc-j-25-Filter.db
abc-j-25-Index.db
abc-j-25-Metadata.db
abc-j-25-Statistics.db
abc-j-25-Summary.db
```

Any bash/python script that can automate this for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to automate this task:

```bash
for file in abc-h-*; do mv "$file" "${file/h/j}"; done
```

Here's a bash script that performs the same task as the above command, but with descriptive variable names:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

old_prefix="abc-h-"
new_prefix="abc-j-"

for filename in "${old_prefix}"*; do
  new_filename="${filename/$old_prefix/$new_prefix}"
  mv "$filename" "$new_filename"
done
```

Here's a Python script that performs the same task as the previous bash scripts:

```py
import os

old_prefix = "abc-h-"
new_prefix = "abc-j-"

for filename in os.listdir():
  if filename.startswith(old_prefix):
    new_filename = filename.replace(old_prefix, new_prefix)
    os.rename(filename, new_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

i write basic script to rename file names according to your requirement and if you want any help for the same comment here

```
import os
path = "folder-path"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        if "abc-h-25-" in filename:
            os.rename(root+filename, root+filename.replace("abc-h-25-", "abc-j-25-" ))
            print(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.rename()` function and `glob` function to rename the files with specific patterns in specific paths. My approach to your problem is as follows.

```
import os
import glob

# Absolute Path of folder with files. 
files_path = r"C:\Users\User1\Documents\GitHub\files"
# Regex Pattern to filter specific files in folder. 
regex_pattern = "abc-h*.db"
all_files = glob.glob(f'{files_path}\{regex_pattern}')

for i in all_files:
    os.rename(i, i.replace("h", "j"))

print("Sucessful!")
```